Apache NetBeans 19 not suggesting imports
Even though I have the import hint checked, JAVA_HOME and PATH
variables setted up, i have the recommended jdk 17 for springboot
3.4.1 all dependecies downloaded through Bundles Maven, The IDE wont
suggest me imports, its driving me NUTS!
i uninstalled everything and reinstalled again same thing...
hint checked
pom
java version

Solved: I just had to remove the 1.18.36 tag for javax.persistence dependancy
